# How to obtain the value of context-root for JRuby/Rails app deployed as a war file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jboss, jruby, warbler

We have a Rails application built with JRuby, and deployed to JBoss as a war file generated by warbler.

In our views, we have link_to calls like so:

```
<%= link_to "link", "path/to/file" %>
```

However, we have set our `context-root` in `jboss-web.xml` to something like:

```
<context-root>my/app</context-root>
```

The end result is that after deploying our war file to JBoss, the links above are broken since they do not include the prefix as specified by the `context-root` value.

Is there any way for me to obtain the value of this `context-root` from JRuby/Rails so that I can fix my links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jruby-rack exposes the context-root as the environment variable `ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT']`. You can find details in the [`setup_relative_url_root`](https://github.com/nicksieger/jruby-rack/blob/master/src/main/ruby/jruby/rack/rails.rb#L32-38) method in jruby-rack.

Using this, I was able to make corrections to the paths that were previously borked.